# This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave

Tags: firefox, drupal, ubuntu-12.04, behat, mink

I am running the behat tests on my site installation. I am getting the following errors when running the tests. I switched into using firefox, because I had issues with the new chromedriver 2.10. Can I work around this one?

**Error message:**

```
Modal dialog present: This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.

Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'jesus-ProLiant-MicroServer', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-32-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_32'

Session ID: 2d072ef8-60e8-494b-b389-96e954041fb0
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=31.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are (officially) out of luck with this. Behat / Mink does not support dialogue handling and throws exceptions when finds one, because it can do nothing about it and it blocks the following steps. There is a [long standing issue on github](https://github.com/Behat/Mink/issues/158) that explains the reasons and I agree with Alexander's last comment:

> Nowadays browser dialogs are considered bad UX and are replaced by
>   nice looking modal windows (at least on websites I was doing), which
>   already can be handled.

Unofficially it's possible if you do a direct call on Selenium Driver, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/blazarecki/2888851) is the best example of how to do it. You can find more about it if you search for "selenium modal window" without Behat references.

```
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession()->accept_alert(); // Ok
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->getWebDriverSession()->dismiss_alert(); // Dismiss
```

Answer (score 1):

> I switched into using firefox, because I had issues with the new chromedriver 2.10. Can I work around this one?

I had similar issues when working with Behat/Mink/Selenium and chromedriver 2.10, an upgrade to chromedriver 2.17 fixed the issues for me.

[http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.17/chromedriver_linux64.zip][1]